# C# ковертация файлов "на лету"

Tags: c#, pdf

Подскажите решение(можно платное) по конвертации любых файлов(файлы офиса, изображения, обычный текст, интернет страницы) в PDF на лету, т.е. без использования виртуального PDF принтера? До и после конвертации файлы должны оставаться в памяти(не сохраняться в файловую систему)

Comment: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b590710c-efe6-4667-842e-2a592ce000cc

Comment: по поводу сохранения в файл и все такое, про stream слышали?

Comment: По поводу stream слышал, и предложенное Вами решение использует Interop. Тем самым сохраняя его на диск.

Comment: А как должен в PDF конвертироваться файл EXE, например?

Comment: Про исполняемые файлы нет речи. Только файлы офиса, изображения, обычный текст, интернет страницы.

Comment: @Atlantis речь шла про "любые файлы"...

Comment: @Atlantis, любой гугл вам подскажет кучу библиотек умеющих работать со стримом, хоть платных хоть бесплатных

Comment: И 99% из них работают через виртуальный pdf принтер, тем самым сохраняя их на диск.

Comment: Если бы я нашёл подходящую я бы не задавал вопрос

Comment: @Atlantis приведите пример кода, который вы пытались использовать

Comment: @Atlantis а в чем проблема с сохранением на диск в качестве промежуточного шага? Из каких соображений у вас появилось это ограничение?

Comment: @PashaPash из-за количества конвертируемых файлов. И ещё конвертер будет реализован как wcf сервис. Мне важно быстродействие. Количество файлов может доходить до нескольких тысяч в день. И они могут быть абсолютно разные по размеру. И сохранение на диск а потом чтение и передача из сервиса - будет отнимать много времени.

Comment: @Atlantis, а вы про Ram Disk, что-то слышали?

Comment: @Dmitry вроде не слышал.

Comment: @Atlantis погуглите, понравится

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо большое за подсказку.

Comment: @Atlantis, Ram Disk, это когда в памяти выдиляется кусок, и он становится диском. Скорость работы с таким диском естественно возрастает. Только не забывайте после оброботки убивать не нужные файлы, ну или копировать их на физический диск.

Comment: @Dmitry у меня все будет на внешнюю сторону отправляться. Ещё раз спасибо.